# No funciona la instrucción using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json

Al escribir `using Newtonsoft.Json` me da error, así como también el `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, sin embargo en otros proyectos que los tengo en uso no me da problemas, que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano

**Actualización**

El error que aparece es el siguiente

> No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'Newtonsoft' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?) El nombre 'JsonConvert' no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Puedes agregar mas información? donde te da error, en que contexto? donde estás incluyendo,el using?

Comment: Debes hacer una referencia al dll que trae el espacio de nombres `Newtonsoft.Json`, normalmente puedes bajar la dll en la página del desarrollador, una vez hecho eso, ya debería estar solucionado.

Comment: Se refiere a que agregues la referencia (ensamblado o dll) al proyecto, eso sí, depende en que IDE y lenguaje estés desarrollando ya que no lo sabemos porque no está en la pregunta. Salutes.

Comment: No entendí eso... no sé que quieres decir

Answer (score 1):

En el proyecto en el que deseas utilizar la librería Newtonsoft la debes agregar como referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O también descargarla desde el **NutGet Package**:

- Abrir la consola desde el menú: "View" > "Other Windows" > "Package Manager
  Console"
- Luego, escribir en la consola: **`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`**

Answer (score 0):

He investigado sobre los *JSON*, y me tiraba error en un ejemplo que copié, donde utilizaban `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

En mi caso lo solucioné usando [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org) (gestor de paquetes). Si estás usando *Visual Studio*, tienes que ir a **Herramientas->Administrador de paquetes**, **NuGet->Adminsitrar Paquetes NuGet** para la *solución*. Seguido de esto se abrirá una ventana con el *administrador de paquetes*, solo tienes que escribir el nombre del paquete y te mostrará alguna sugerencia, en mi caso `Newtonsoft.Json`. Lo seleccionas y le das en *instalar* (para tu *solución* o todo el proyecto), ya instalado, ni siquiera tienes que poner un `using Newtonsoft.Json`, ya que lo puedes invocar así, `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tu_objeto)`.